# Why are there so many formats for local IP address?

Tags: networking, ip

If I enter the following command in CMD prompt...

```
netstat -ano
```

I get a list of active connections as expected. What confuses me is that there are many different formats for my "Local Address"...

```
Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       656
TCP    208.80.154.224:13      0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
TCP    127.0.0.1:2559         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       8628
TCP    [::]:135               [::]:0                 LISTENING       656
UDP    [::1]:1900             *:*                                    4512
```

For a particular connection, what determines which format is used for my "Local Address"? i.e. why is 0.0.0.0 displayed for some connections and [::] displayed for other connections, and so on?

Comment: You cannot be "hacked" just by posting an IP address.  You have to have a vulnerable application running on the system that normally would allow somebody to connect ( i.e. a server application ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

netstat shows which ip adresses and ports are being listened on, because a program requested this.

0.0.0.0 means: any IP4 address.

208... is your public ip address that is being listed on.

127.0.0.1 is your local ip address, also known as local host, which would indicate that the program needs to open a port, but only does this so it can connect to itself.

192. (or whatever your network ip address would be) is for LAN connections only.

:: is an IP v6 address which means: it listens to any ip v6 address, similar as 0.0.0.0

::1 is ipv6's version of local host, similar to 127.0.0.1 meaning that its only used for communication to itself. The PID is the program that initiated the command. You can find this number in the task manager under processes.

Comment: So if the local address for a connection is 127.0.0.1 (as opposed to 208.80.154.224 or something like that), then the "foreign" application  is running on your own machine. That makes sense.

Comment: No. All applications are running on your pc. If an application looks for traffic on IP 127.0.0.1, it will only accept traffic sent from this pc. If an application looks for traffic on your public internet IP, it expects the traffic to come from the internet, and will not accept traffic that is on your local network.

Comment: Okay, so if "Local Address" is your machine's public internet IP (not 127.0.0.1), then the "Foreign Address" is most likely the IP address of some machine elsewhere on the internet? Correct?

Comment: Yes. It is listening to a connection from that IP, because that ip connected to your machine first. When you want to transmit data from a server, the client first has to connect, then the server knows where it is going to send its data.

Comment: To clarify what I mean with the above: A server has one listening port that clients can connect to. If the server used that port to transmit all the data, only one client could connect. Instead the server notes the ip address from the client, then sets up a new connection towards the client using a different port, specifically for that client.

Comment: `192` is not only for LAN connections. There are millions of public IP addresses starting with `192`.

Comment: @kasperd please reread what I said: 192. (or whatever your network ip would be) Which basically means, whenever your LAN connection is mentioned, it refers to LAN traffic only.